# rpm: dependencies not failing on simultaneous installation/upgrade of multiple packages

Tags: rpm

I have an issue with rpm that has me tearing my hair out.

We have created multiple packages for deployment onto internal servers - some of these are base packages (shared libraries) that are used across different (but related) systems and some of these are application-specific libraries.

To simplify, the packages and requirements are as follows:

```
SharedLib-ver.x
ApplicationLib-ver.x  [Requires SharedLib-ver.x]
UserInterface-ver.x   [Requires ApplicationLib-ver.x]
```

To install, the sysadmin has been using the atomic command

```
rpm -Uvh SharedLib.rpm ApplicationLib.rpm UserInterface.rpm
```

This has been working fine as long as all the packages install correctly, but does NOT work as I would expect if any of the packages fails to install.

We have verified, under test conditions, that rpm is correctly establishing the dependencies and is attempting to install/upgrade the packages in the correct order, regardless of the order in which they are included in the atomic rpm -Uvh  command.

The specific problem comes when one of the packages fails in the %pre stage (i.e. %pre has a non-zero exit status)

If installing using the atomic installation/upgrade command as shown above, it correctly reports that

```
error: %pre(SharedLib-ver.x.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
```

***but***, it continues to upgrade/install the dependent packages regardless.

However, if the packages are upgraded/installed sequentially, i.e.:

```
rpm -Uvh SharedLib.rpm; 
rpm -Uvh ApplicationLib.rpm; 
rpm -Uvh UserInterface.rpm;
```

it fails installing SharedLib with the same error as above, and then correctly refuses to install the remaining packages as the dependencies haven't been met. This is the behaviour that I would expect.

For what it's worth, the same thing also happens if the %pretrans scriptlet terminates with a non-zero exit state (by definition, I thought the pretrans was supposed to be completed *before* the rpm transaction starts!). I have seen it suggested that explicit dependency/version checking could be included in the %pretrans section, but this feels entirely wrong to me and seems to defeat the whole reason for using a package manager in the first place!

The rpm version is 4.8.0 and we have verified this behaviour on both CentOs and RedHat servers.

So firstly, is it actually possible to install multiple packages in a single atomic command such as that shown, whilst respecting the dependencies provided by those packages?

And if so, how can I achieve this?

I'm sure the reason and/or solution is trivial, but I have been going round in circles on this one and cannot seem to find a resolution.

### EDIT

Further to Matt Schuchard's comments (thank you) I have tried the 'yum install' approach.

Cutting out script output and other extraneous info, running:

```
yum install ApplicationLib-ver.x.noarch.rpm UserInterface-ver.x.noarch.rpm SharedLib-ver.x.noarch.rpm
```

gives

```
Examining UserInterface-ver.x.noarch.rpm: UserInterface-ver.x.noarch
Marking UserInterface-ver.x.noarch.rpm to be installed
Examining SharedLib-ver.x.noarch.rpm: SharedLib-ver.x.noarch
Marking SharedLib-ver.x.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package UserInterface.noarch 0:ver.x will be installed
---> Package ApplicationLib.noarch 0:ver.x will be installed
---> Package SharedLib.noarch 0:ver.x will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                  Arch                    Version                     Repository                                                Size
=============================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 UserInterface                            noarch                     x                     /UserInterface-ver.x.noarch                                 203 k
 ApplicationLib                           noarch                     x                     /ApplicationLib-ver.x.noarch                                2.0 M
 SharedLib                                noarch                     x                     /SharedLib-ver.x.noarch                                      19 M

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================
Install       3 Package(s)

Total size: 21 M
Installed size: 21 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction

error: %pretrans(SharedLib-ver.x.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
Error in PRETRANS scriptlet in rpm package SharedLib-ver.x.noarch

  Verifying  : ApplicationLib-ver.x.noarch                                                                                                   1/3
  Verifying  : UserInterface-ver.x.noarch                                                                                                    2/3
  Verifying  : SharedLib-ver.x.noarch                                                                                                        3/3

Installed:
  UserInterface.noarch 0:ver.x                                        ApplicationLib.noarch 0:ver.x

Failed:
  SharedLib.noarch 0:ver.x

Complete!
```

So yum is getting the base dependencies and install order right (presumably from rpm anyway) but after doing a 'yum install <packages>', rpm -qa shows ApplicationLib and UserInterface installed, but SharedLib NOT installed, which is the exact same problem I have when installing directly with rpm!

Just to be absolutely 100% certain, I have un-installed everything and then tried (in turn) to rpm install, rpm upgrade and yum install ApplicationLib-ver.x.noarch and in *every* case, it fails as would be expected because the SharedLib is not present.

### EDIT (2)

Thanks, Jeff, for your additional response.

I am 100% trying to avoid any "fancy" scripting in the %pre tests - that just feels fundamentally like it is trying to coerce a behaviour that (if everything is set up right), should be dealt with intrinsically by rpm.

My first approach was (exactly as you suggest) - to add narrow (version specific) dependencies

i.e. in ApplicationLib

```
Requires: SharedLib = %{version}
```

and in UserInterface,

```
Requires: ApplicationLib = %{version}
```

Where the expansion of %{version} is the same in all cases

This works perfectly if the packages are installed sequentially, but what still confuses me is why rpm/yum will skip the SharedLib, but nevertheless continues to install packages that are dependent on it if all three packages are installed in a single command.

It might make things clearer if I explain that these packages constitute a back-end web application and updating some parts but not others risks at best, causing an unsatisfactory user experience and at worst, data corruption. To minimise this risk, the SharedLib completes a number of pre-install tests to ensure that the system is safe and ready to accept an update (e.g. that the webserver is in a safe state to continue with the installation - present and stopped) and a number of other housekeeping tasks (e.g. stopping custom services which are also part of the application, versioned log rotation etc) if it is safe to proceed.

If the server is (for example) present but running and serving pages, it is not safe to continue with any step of the upgrade so the sharedLib rpm exits and explains to the sysadmin what is required to continue safely. Clearly, if the dependent libraries are installed regardless of a failure in the base dependency, this is an undesirable situation.

OK, so this is pretty much an insurance policy against hasty fingers (the installation instructions are already explicit in that the server must not be running), but it doesn't seem an unreasonable thing to be doing (YMMV!)

I can, of course, just mandate that the rpms are not installed in a single-line yum/rpm command, but this just feels like something that rpm should be able to handle predictably, provided I get everything set up correctly, on top of which there is no *guarantee* that any such instructions will be adhered to anyway.

Comment: If you use the OS package manager to install instead of `rpm` then this will not occur.

Comment: @Matt-schuchard Maybe I'm missing something here - I'm trying to install this on RedHat servers (with CentOs as a test environment) and was under the impression that rpm _is_ the RedHat Package Manager?
Anyway, that's (to a certain extent) by-the-by - the specification requires that the package is distributed via rpm. It works as expected when installed sequentially, but not if attempted in a single transaction (irrespective of %pretrans scriptlets)

Comment: If you use dnf/zypper/yum then you will be fine. Note this is more of a workaround than  a solution, but at the same time installing with rpm instead of the OS package manager is generally discouraged.

Comment: So, if I understand this right, you are suggesting that I continue to _create and distribute_ the packages as rpms as normal, but tell the sysadmin to use _yum_ to install them, rather than using the native rpm install/upgrade route? OK, that's worth a go :-)
However, out of curiosity **is** there a solution to my original problem, or is that a known shortcoming with rpm (if it is, it's a pretty whopping big shortcoming if you ask me!)

Comment: So I only just realized this is a `%preinstall` error. That may not be treated as a fatal install error (notice it occurs during verification) during the total packages' install which could be the problem here.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that clearer - I have tried creating rpms both with the SharedLib rpm throwing a non-zero exit in %pretrans and also with no %pretrans section and a non-zero exit occurring in %pre: the result is the same in either case, whether using 'yum install <packages>' or doing 'rpm -Uvh <packages>' :-(

Comment: No, that was my bad for not reading more thoroughly. Also my apologies since I cannot help further at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you wish all-or-nothing atomic upgrade behavior for 3 packages with rpm and are attempting to enforce that with scripted tests.

You are never going to succeed with scripts using %pretrans because of the context: nothing in the current transaction set is installed when %pretrans scripts are run; hence you cannot write a script that tests for successful install.

You seem to be expecting that a %pre failure in a prerequisite will cause dependent packages to also fail. That isn't how %pre works: a failure of %pre will cause that package to be skipped (with a warning). That is actually what you are seeing with both rpm/yum, the main difference is that yum appears to block the warning message from rpm.

(aside)
You likely can add explicit %pre tests of prerequisites to skip installs of dependent packages if a prerequisite fails to install, but that still isn't all-or-nothing atomic behavior because rpm will not undo successful installs
that have already been performed.

Meanwhile scripting %pre tests isn't the right approach. You need to focus on the failure modes of your application. Presumably, you are worried about UI failures when libraries are upgraded underneath a running application. First, running applications have a reference count on shared libraries and will continue to run even when libraries are removed by package upgrades.

If, say, your application invokes an executable that is somehow incompatible after/during an upgrade, then that needs to be dealt with in the application, not in the packaging.

Otherwise adding narrow (i.e. use specific version&release) dependencies will ensure that all-or-none of the packages are included in the upgrade transaction. RPM (short of exceptional pathologies like power off and/or no disk space, or buggy packaging, or buggy rpm) will succeed in installing.

So what type of failures are you worried about? There's likely a solution ...

Comment: Thanks for your response, Jeff. 

I have added some more specific use-case information (EDIT (2)) to my original question, that hopefully makes it clearer what I am trying to achieve and why.

Comment: OK. So it seems you have a complicated pre-install test in SharedLib that sometimes requires manual intervention from a sysadmin. Splitting the distribution (i.e. the install) from the restarting would permit fully automated installation. Basically, put a version on the directories used to avoid all content replacements and instrument a restart using the last known good content for running. Otherwise you will need to construct the pre-install script so that the script automates the fixing and avoids manual intervention somehow.

Comment: BTW, there is a %verifyscript script run by rpm --verify that might be populated to run the preinstall script. That would permit manual instructions like "Run rpm --verify SharedLib and fix all problems before upgrading the application."

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. Will get my teeth into those suggestions and see how I get on!